# Why This expression accepting & symbol

Tags: c#, regex, regular-language

I have this regex expression but it accepting **&**  symbol.

```
string REGEX_ALPHANUMERIC_UNDERSCORE_NOSPACE = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_-,!.]+$";
```

I am not getting why it is accepting **&**  symbol.
Please help anyone
Thanks

Comment: Are you saying you want to include characters `_` through to `,`? or that you want to include `_`, `-`, and `,`?

Comment: I want to include only these _ - , ! .

Comment: At the moment C# is interpreting `_-,` as a range, and is actually throwing an exception for me: `[x-y] range in reverse order.` You need to escape the range character ( - ) as in malbarmawai's answer.

Comment: `[_-,]` denotes a _range_ from `_` to `,`. Usually, when `&` is accepted, this means that `&` is in the Unicode range between those two characters. For C# this may be different, or should throw an error, as John said. Just use `-` at the end of the character class to make it unambiguous, or escape it as `\-` or something similar.

Comment: @Xufox It does not work, Could you please help in this

Comment: @Taylor What does not work? We can't help with "it".

Comment: @Taylor have you try this `"^[a-zA-Z0-9_\\-,!.]+$"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
string REGEX_ALPHANUMERIC_UNDERSCORE_NOSPACE = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_\\-,!.]+$";
```

Comment: It is still accepting  &  symbol. what could be the alternative solution

Comment: I have test it at http://regexstorm.net/tester and it 's not accepting & symbol

Comment: Frankly OP should have been getting an exception from the original expression, so I'm thinking that this might not be the expression that's actually being used.

Comment: @malbarmawi I am running in Visual studio and checking in a browser. But unfortunately, it is still accepting.

Comment: @John sorry I don't get what you said :\

Comment: @malbarmawi http://rextester.com/SEEON97619 - OP's expression as it stands produces an exception. OP said it was accepting `&`. If it throws an exception, it can't accept anything. This leads me to think that the expression OP provided is not the expression OP used.

Comment: @Taylor I have update my answer

Comment: @malbarmawi Thanks, yes finally it works. Thank you